# Window doesn't show up on the screen

Tags: c, linux, x11

I am new to X11, so I tried to compile&run this code

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
int screen_num;
Display *display;
int screen_width;
int screen_height;
Window root_window;
Window win;
int win_width, win_height;
int win_x, win_y;
int border_width = 4;

unsigned long white_pixel;
unsigned long black_pixel;

display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
root_window = RootWindow(display, screen_num);
screen_width = DisplayWidth(display, screen_num);
screen_height = DisplayHeight(display, screen_num);

white_pixel = WhitePixel(display, screen_num);
black_pixel = BlackPixel(display, screen_num);

win_width = screen_width / 3;
win_height = screen_height / 3;

win_x = screen_width / 3;
win_y = screen_height / 3;

char window_name[] = "Basic Window Program";

XEvent report;
GC gc;
if (display == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot connect to X server");
    exit(-1);
}
//  printf("Height:\t%dpx\n"\
    "Width:\t%dpx\n"\
    "White px.:\t%d\n"\
    "Black px.:\t%d\n",
//      screen_height, screen_width,
//      white_pixel, black_pixel);

win=XCreateSimpleWindow(display,DefaultRootWindow(display),0,0, 
    200, 300, 5, white_pixel, black_pixel);
XClearWindow(display, win);
XMapRaised(display, win);
system("sleep 10");
}
```

The commented code works OK, and all the values are printed correctly? but the window refuses to show up. I run it on Debian 9, compile with

```
gcc -L/usr/X11/lib/ -lx11
```

Everything else works. I have the last version of libx11-dev, and variations of keyboard-interracting code run OK.

Comment: Why so many `-Wunused-variable` and `-Wunused-but-set-variable` warnings? Make sure you have warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The X11 protocol allows a client application to queue up a series of actions to be performed on a given display, and then send them to the display server all at once, reducing the number of network round-trips required to do anything.  (This was much more important back in the day, when client applications were more commonly at the other end of a slow TCP connection from the display server.)

Xlib assumes that it should queue all display actions up until (a) it runs out of internal buffer space, (b) you request the next input event, or (c) you explicitly *flush* the queue of pending actions (this is referred to as the "output buffer" or "output queue" in the Xlib manpages).

Your program hasn't gotten to the point where it's ready to process input events yet, so you need an explicit flush:  change this

```
XMapRaised(display, win);
system("sleep 10");
}
```

to this

```
XMapRaised(display, win);
XFlush(display);
system("sleep 10");
}
```

and the window will appear. I would also like to suggest that you change this

```
system("sleep 10");
}
```

to this

```
sleep(10);
return 0;
}
```

because, if there's a way to do something *without* using `system`, that way is almost always better; and because relying on the implicit `return 0` at the end of `main` is bad style.

Comment: Other alternative is to make use of your `report` variable and set up a simple event loop calling `XNextEvent(display, &report);` (then you can get rid of the kludge of `system("sleep 10");` and just press any key to exit) And you may want to change the order to `black_pixel, white_pixel)` in your `XCreateSimpleWindow` call.